# SQL Server RANK() start with 1

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table like:

```
create table t1 (d1 date)
```

There is no key so dates can repeat. I want to select distinct dates in descending order with rank, such that the rank starts with 1 and sequentially increments.

```
Date         Rank
----------   ----
2020-01-29   1
2020-01-24   2
2020-01-22   3
```

I am not an expert in SQL and when I looked up doc on `RANK()` I found the rank numbers to be **non-deterministic**.

So I am looking to achieve this in an efficient way with or without `RANK()`.

I already tried as someone asked about `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d1) AS Rank  
FROM
    t1 
ORDER BY
    d1 DESC
```

But this would produce something like:

```
Date         Rank
----------   ----
2020-01-29   123
2020-01-24   122
2020-01-22   121
```

Comment: `rank()` should be fine. What is your issue with that ? Or have you take a look at `row_number()`  also ?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I want the rank numbers to be 1, 2, 3 but as it turns out they are sequential but not starting from 1. The starting number is arbitrary

Comment: can you post your full statement with your attempt at RANK() ? and do you have duplicates? I suggest ROW_NUMBER() too, or DENSE_RANK() if you have duplicates.

Comment: As the question mentions, there is no key so yes there are dupes and I have also tried ROW_NUMBER. (query in question) I have tried DENSE_RANK as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. As you have duplicate `d1` in table, you need to `group by` the `d1` column

```
select d1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d1 DESC) AS [Rank]  
from    t1 
group by d1
order by d1 desc
```

or if you prefer to use `distinct`

```
select  d1, rank() over (order by d1 desc) as [Rank]
from
(
    select  distinct d1
    from    t1 
) d
order by [Rank]
```

Or `dense_rank()`

```
select  distinct d1, dense_rank() over (order by d1 desc) as [Rank]
from    t1
order by [Rank]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d1 desc)AS Rank 
FROM t1

SELECT DISTINCT d1,
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY d1 desc)AS [Rank] 
FROM t1
ORDER BY [Rank]
```

Comment: You should at least give a short description of your code block. If not just give an official documentation reference of important function used in your code.

Comment: @SurajKumar okay next time i will takecare. Thanks!